# 403 error when trying to access local webserver that is configured to allow from LAN

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, http, lamp

I have a local web server that is public for specific IPs including *all* IPs in my LAN.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.2.1/24
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Line 3 is supposed to allow all IPs in my local network and it works fine except for the computer the server is running on. When I try to access the folder, where this `.htaccess` file is located, I recieve a 403 status code.

I tried adding `allow from 127.0.0.1` but it had no effect.

**How can I allow the host computer to access the web server?**

I only recieve this error when I use `localhost` however it works when I use my IP address `192.168.2.XXX`.

I'm running Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) PHP/7.1.4.

Comment: Does it have IPv6 enabled? It might be using `::1` in that case.

Comment: @Seth That's it. I didn't think about that. Could you write an answer, so that I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a server is enabled to use the IPv6 protocol (even if it only has a link local address) he might be using the IPv6 local address (`::1`).